# Как телеграмм боту на Python реагировать на закрытие опроса?

Tags: python, aiogram

пишу телеграмм бота опросника на языке программирования Python, я бы хотел при закрытие опроса подсчитать голоса. Закрываю опрос через `send_poll(close_date=time()+ 5)`
Вот код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["vote"], commands_prefix="!")
async def vote(message: types.message):
    global a
    global b
    m = await bot.send_poll(chat_id = message.chat.id, question='кикнуть', options=['Да', 'Нет'],  is_anonymous=False, close_date = time()+5)
    a = 0
    b = 0
@dp.poll_answer_handler()
async def handle_poll_answer(quiz_answer:types.Pollanswer):
        global a
        global b
        if quiz_answer.option_ids == [1]:
            a += 1
            print(a)
        elif quiz_answer.option_ids ==[0]:
            b += 1
            print(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из того, что я понял, ловить момент автоматического закрытия невозможно.

Но можно сделать небольшой костыль с помощью asyncio.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    time = 5
    msg = await bot.send_poll(chat_id=message.chat.id, question="Вопрос", options=["Вариант 1", "Вариант 2"])
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    poll = await bot.stop_poll(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=msg.message_id)
    print(poll)
```

В `poll` будет храниться данные о нем.
Пример

```
{"id": "...", "question": "Вопрос", "options": [{"text": "Вариант 1", "voter_count": 1}, {"text": "Вариант 2", "voter_count": 0}], "total_voter_count": 1, "is_closed": true, "is_anonymous": true, "type": "regular", "allows_multiple_answers": false}
```